# pip3 not found in Docker Alpine

Tags: python, django, docker, alpine-linux

I'm brand new to Docker and have been trying to containerize my Django application. Whenever I run `docker-compose up`, I get:

```
 => ERROR [ 6/15] RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt                                                      0.2s 
------                                                                                                           
 > [ 6/15] RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt:                                                                 
#10 0.207 /bin/sh: pip3: not found
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine

# Add scripts to PATH of running container
ENV PATH='/scripts:${PATH}:/sbin'

# Packages required on alpine in order to install uWSGI server used to run
# Django application in production
RUN apk update
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp gcc libc-dev linux-headers
RUN apk add python3
RUN apk add py3-pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

I ran `docker run -i -t alpine /bin/sh` in my shell and, when I ran `apk add python3`, I verified that it does not provide `pip`, so I install `pip` and tried `pip install ...` and it successfully installed package. However, these commands do not seem to work in my Dockerfile. How can I fix this?

I have tried running `pip install`, `pip3 install`, `py-pip install`, and `py3-pip install`, and nothing works.

Comment: (A `python` base image should already include Python; you do not need to separately install it using a package manager.)